# Where to place a data array in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to create the following static data array in my zf2 project so that routing and others methods can be done based on department codes, and then view helpers and form select elements in different modules look up the department titles for the user interface.

```
    $deptList = array(
        '01'  => 'Human Resources',
        '02'  => 'Sales',
        '03'  => 'Marketing',
        '04'  => 'Accounting',  
           // ...           
    );
```

In the zf2 directory structure, where should I put this?  Does it need it's own class?

Also, it might be convenient to record this data in a database table instead of hard-coding it.  But I question whether this would affect performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no registry singleton like in ZF1 creating a service and injecting it where needed is appropriate. You can then place it according to your autoloader configuration in the filesystem.  As well inside that class you could do anything you like to build the array, e.g. using a database for it.

Nevertheless you can as well use your config for it if it is static information - e.g. like this:

*Module.php*

```
class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

*module.config.php*

```
return [
    'deptList' => [
        '01' => 'Human Resources',
        '02' => 'Sales',
        '03' => 'Marketing',
        '04' => 'Accounting',
        // ...           
    ],
];
```

*MyController.php*

```
class MyController extends \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController
{

    public function myAction()
    {
        $config   = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
        $deptList = $config['deptList'];
    }

}
```